# Continuous keyboard movements

Tags: c++, allegro5

Now I am making a game where there are two plates on both sides of the screen (i.e. Left and right). And a ball which bounces in the screen. When it touches either of the plates then it bounces back. But if it touches left or right edge of the screen then it's game over. We have to control the plates by arrow keys or standard (W, A, S, D) keys. Now my problem is when I press W or any movement keys it moves once then stops.

I have to press it many times to make it move. I want continuous movement when I press and hold any of my movement keys. I am using allegro 5 with Dev c++ on windows 7 PC.

Comment: Do a toggle, movement is enabled when a keydown event is detected, and disabled when a keyup event is detected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to track the state of the keys. When you get a key down event, set the keydown to true. When you get a key up event, set the keydown to false.

Then in your update function, check if the key is down and then move.

Something like this makes it very easy :

```
bool keys[ALLEGRO_KEY_MAX] = {0};

/// In event loop
if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_DOWN) {
   keys[ev.keyboard.keycode] = true;
}
else if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_KEY_UP) {
   keys[ev.keyboard.keycode] = false;
}

if (ev.type == ALLEGRO_EVENT_TIMER) {
   if (keys[ALLEGRO_KEY_W]) {
      player.y -= YSPEED;
   }
   if (keys[ALLEGRO_KEY_S]) {
      player.y += YSPEED;
   }
}
```

You can also monitor the keyboard state with al_get_keyboard_state, but it's not guaranteed to be accurate due to the time difference between when allegro receives a key event and you do.

Answer (score 0):

The event processing logic should respond to keypresses and update the **velocity** of the plate, and the update logic should move the plate according to the velocity. Here's some pseudocode:

```
while running:
    # event processing
    for event in queue:
        if event is keypress:
            if key is W:
                velocityY -= 10
            if key is S:
                velocityY += 10
        if event is keyrelease:
            if key is W:
                velocityY += 10
            if key is S:
                velocityY -= 10

    # update
    posY += velocityY * elapsedTime
```

Comment: That's exactly what I did @rcorre but then when I press up arrow key it moves once and when I release it, it moves back and travels back the distance it previously covered.

Answer (score -1):

hi in the pseudo code if event keypress (Allegro_event_key down) should detect a key press and in the appropiate key will do its logic in the allegro_event_key_up you should stop the logic from doing stuff.

For instance if the key is pressed do something and when key up stop doing something.

I hope that helps. Regards and thank you.